# Is possible to add custom fields to PHP ini file?

Tags: php

I want to know if is possible to add custom *fields* to the PHP ini file and get it with the `ini_get` function.

This code works fine:

```
;PHP ini file
mysqli.default_host=localhost

# PHP code
ini_get('mysqli.default_host')
```

**But I want to do something like this (isn't working):**

```
;PHP ini file
my_custom_field=custom_value

# PHP code
ini_get('my_custom_field')
```

Is possible to do this? Because when I do this to custom fields, it returns `false`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of using your .ini file?

Comment: Did you restart your webserver after making the changes?

Comment: I tested it and doesn't works. This is questios is for me know if it really doesn't works or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`php.ini` is for PHP configuration, unless you are making an extension (written in C) you probably shouldn't add new options to it. If you are making a configuration for a specific site/application create your own `config.ini` file inside that project's root. You can then use [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to get the values from it.

If you really must add custom entries to your `php.ini` you can get them using [get_cfg_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php), not [ini_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).